# Get a text between an html tag and a specific character

Tags: php, html, regex

In the following string I need to extract only 2014-04-19 using php and regex with preg_match

```
 ...</abbr></td><td><abbr class="dtend" title="2014-04-19T00:00:00+00:00">19 Apr 2014</abbr></td></tr>...
```

The preg_match and regex string I use is:

```
preg_match("/class=\"dtend\" title=\"(.*)\"\>/i", $str,$str2);
```

The string I obtain is:

```
2014-04-19T00:00:00+00:00
```

After "T" numbers (time) are obviously random.
I amm not very experienced, neither novice, but really can't fix the issue. Can you provide a suggestion/some help?

Comment: Well, going by instinct, you could split by capital T and get the first chunk. What you need to do depends on all possible input scenarios that you want to handle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your regex is incomplete. Change it to this:

```
"/class=\"dtend\" title=\"(.*)T.*\"\>/i"
```

That way, the capture group only captures up to the first `T`.

Answer (score 3):

Might use a [lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) to meet `T`, there are many ways to do it:

```
$pattern = '/class="dtend" title="\K[^"]+(?=T)/i';
```

- [\K](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-php.html#k) resets the beginning of the match, which will be in `$out[0]` then.
- Used `[^"]+` as charcters to be matched (`+` one or more characters, that are not `"`)

[Test on regex101.com](http://regex101.com/r/jM7vS3)

For further regex info see the [FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22937618/reference-what-does-this-regex-mean/22944075#22944075).

Comment: I like this approach, didn't know about `\K`.

Answer (score 0):

you can use:

```
preg_match("/class=\"dtend\" title=\"([0-9\\-]+)[^\"]+\"\>/i", $str,$str2);
```

`([0-9\\-]+)` will fetch any numberic symbols or `-` (NOTE: because of multiple escaping you may need to use tree/four `\` here)

`[^\"]+` - skip all non `"` symbols

Answer (score 0):

Why using a regelar expression on a known giving string ?

you should do something like this -

```
$var = '<td>T<abbr class="dtend" title="2014-04-19T00:00:00+00:00">19 Apr 2014</abbr></td></tr>';

$string_to_search = 'class="dtend" title="';

$start = strpos($var, $string_to_search);

$var = substr($var,$start+strlen($string_to_search),10);
```

It might look worst as regex do it in a simpler way but as long you know what you expecting you should always use simple string functions instead of regex.